# undefined reference C file

Tags: c, undefined-reference

I use on libnfc project on github:

when i try to compile this file

https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/examples/pn53x-diagnose.c

i got error of `undefined reference to pn53x_transceive'`

on line 106+117

why? on line 53 it do  `#include "libnfc/chips/pn53x.h"`
and on this file:
https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/libnfc/chips/pn53x.h
i have this function (line 305):

```
int    pn53x_transceive(struct nfc_device *pnd, const uint8_t *pbtTx, const size_t szTx, uint8_t *pbtRx, const size_t szRxLen, int timeout);
```

what can i do please?
thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are missing `topn53x_transceive` function. Is it included in project on Github somewhere?

Comment: @tilz0R i edit ..please read again ',I include the file pn53x.h and there is the function

Comment: Read [ask] and provide all required information **in the question itself**!

Comment: Maybe the loader/linker doesn't know where to find it?

Comment: Although the duplicate is for C++ rather than C, the basic ideas apply.  Using a header declares things; you have to provide a library to get the definition of functions and variables declared in headers.  (There's a standard library that provides a lot of standard functions that is linked automatically; for functions not in that library, you need to add the alternative to the linking command line — after the object (or source) files.)

Answer (score 0):

You know the header file which declares the interface to the `pn53x_transceive` function. Now you need to find out which file contains that function's implementation, and link that file (it might be a library) to your executable.